# Automake dependencies generation

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am using automake on Debian Squeeze for compiling a very simple C project with 6 source files.

The issue comes when I try to compile the sources using the generated Makefile. One of the sources (`ll_socket.c`) uses system libraries like `<sys/socket.h>` and `<net/if.h>`. Those dependencies should appear in the `.deps/ll_socket.Tpo` file automatically generated; however, that file is empty and therefore when GCC tries to compile that file, it cannot find the dependencies for the compilation.

Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure these files in `net/` exist and are in your include path? Automake tracks dependencies while compiling, so a first build should update `.deps/ll_socket.Tpo`. If that first compile fails it won't be updated.

Comment: I have been taking a closer look at the output of the gcc as invoked by the automatically generated Makefile and it comes out that the problem is related with the compiler. The option "-std=cc99" deactivates the macro "__USE_MISC" which defines the structure "ifreq" inside the "net/if.h" header file. I am now trying to activate it for getting those definitions.